# How to Print and style Profile2 fields?

Tags: users

I created a profiles type called: Game Player Profile (Machine name: game_player_profile). This contains : field_firstname, field_lastname, field_profilephoto, field_zipcode.....

How do I print and style these fields to create a page with a list of the 'Game Players' First Names + Last Names + Photo.....

Thanks

J.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Views Module.  It is the primary module used to select fields and display them. You can find out just about everything you need to know about using the module in [this Video series](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone)